# CSS Drop-Shadow on nav with background image

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I've got a navigation bar at the top of the page that has a `box-shadow`, but it doesn't seem to apply to the `section` element below with a background url. If I comment out the `background` attribute, the drop shadow is apparent.

Here is the codepen:
http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/ByxeGR

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="header">
  <span class="brand">BRAND</span>
  <ul class="link">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="blog-container">
  <section>

  </section> 
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  height: 4em;
  .brand {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding-left: 1em;
  }
  .link {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    flex: 1 auto; // stretch to end of width
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    li {
      padding-right: 1em;
    }
  }
}

.blog-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: url(https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1414490929659-9a12b7e31907?q=75&fm=jpg&s=f838066e7aa9eab9d1ccc28fd5ec9574) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  section {
    height: 20em;
  }
}
```

How can I get the drop shadow to appear over the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `position: relative;` to your `.header` style.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPLoGN

Comment: I should've included this, but didn't think it would pertain to the solution. I eventually want the header to retain a fixed position on scroll.

Comment: Works with `display: fixed` as well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I forked your example on codepen: [Link](http://codepen.io/erhankaradeniz/pen/myLZEm)

```
position: relative;
```

You need to add position to the header for it to work properly. (I added z-index, as well but relative seems to fix your issue as well. Credits for author below me)

Comment: I should've included this, but didn't think it would pertain to the solution. I eventually want the header to retain a fixed position on scroll.